# Run integration tests in-memory(embedded) MongoDB in Spring application

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, integration-testing, in-memory-database

I am trying to make the integration tests run in memory in MongoDB. I would appreciate any idea or suggestion.
What I did:

- A dependency on de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo is added to provide embedded MongoDB for integration tests.
- The embedmongo-maven-plugin is added to start or stop an instance of MongoDB during a Maven build.
  My idea here is when I run 'mvn clean test' command the integration tests  connect to the embedded mongo instance and not the "live" one(mongo-java-driver). After running test, I can see in the consolo log embedded mongo is started:

  o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-08-04T15:23:14.303+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **MongoDB starting :** pid=26673 port=54871 dbpath=/var/folders/qv/......

However, I think it doesn't work as expected. Because, in the console log, I can also see:

```
org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=...
```

If I shut down the live instance of Mongo, tests failed. :(
Is there anyone to help me to overcome this issue? I want to thank in advance for your time.